# Slick carousel only displays first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm having a problem whereby only the first appended element to a div is appearing as a 'slick' carousel.

```
        $('.multiple-items').append('<div class="iimg"><img src="'+logo+'"><p>'+streamName+' is playing '+game+'</p><p>Viewers: '+viewers+'</p></div>');


        });
```

and

```
        if (dataOffline.logo !== null){
            $('.offline').append('<div class="iimg"><img src="'+dataOffline.logo+'"></div>');
        } 

            else {
            $('.offline').append('<div><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>');
        }
```

are extracts from the callback functions of two getJSON requests. In each case I have appended a div containing an image and paragraphs in the first and just images in the second. When these operations are completed I call

```
$('.multiple-items').not('.slick-initialized').slick();
$('.offline').not('.slick-initialized').slick();
```

However absolutely nothing happens. In earlier versions the slick carousel was working fine so there is no issue with links in my html code. Can anyone advise as to how I can obtain two neat carousels? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your carousel is already initialised then you can use `slickAdd`, otherwise you can append your image and then initialise. For your offline carousel it might look something like:

```
var slideToAdd = '<div><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>';
if(dataOffline.logo !== null){
    slideToAdd = '<div class="iimg"><img src="' + dataOffline.logo + '"></div>';
}

var offline = $('.offline');
if(offline.hasClass('slick-initialized')){
    offline.slick('slickAdd',slideToAdd);
} else {
    offline.append(slideToAdd);
    offline.slick();
}
```

Comment: Your solution is better. 

Answer (score 0):

After the carousel is initialized, the DOM is manipulated. Arrows, dots, classes, and a lot of other stuff is added.

You must uninitialize the entire carousel if you add an image.

```
// this will work
$('.multiple-items').slick();
$('.multiple-items').slick('unslick');
$('.multiple-items').append('<img src="...">');
$('.multiple-items').slick();
```